# MySQL Select returns an empty ResultSet though data is in DB? Different connections get different results

Tags: java, mysql, spring-jdbc

We have two applications servers communicating with the same DB. One is a TCP server and the other is an HTTP server (we want to replace the old TCP one with the new HTTP server..but need them to work together for a time.)

Both server communicate with the DB in the same way. Spring-JDBC with exactly the same code.

When running this setup on a testing env everything works fine, but when deployed in production on the cloud server, a very strange phenomenon presents itself.

It seems like (just a guess, I may be completely wrong) the db connections somehow "block" or "lock" each other out from ***specific rows***. Although none of the MySQL queries use locks.

What happens is for example this query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '?'` on the HTTP server returns an empty ResultSet for ?=x, and the same exact query returns the correct row when run from the TCP server for x. The row is indeed in the db and should not return empty.

The code running this query on both servers is the following:

```
public UserDBO getUserRecord(String uid) throws SQLException {
    UserDBO result = null;
    try {
        JdbcOperations jdbcOperations = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String query = "SELECT *" + " FROM " + TABLE_USERS + " WHERE " + COL_UID + "=" + quote(uid);
        logger.config("Executing SQL query:[" + query + "]");
        result = jdbcOperations.queryForObject(query, new UserDboRowMapper());
    } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException ignored) {}
    return result;
}
```

Both of the server DAO's use the same user account to connect to the db. Checking server configuration shows that it should not be a problem ('max concurrent connections per account' and all other relevant configurations are not limited).

We know the problem is not in the code since as stated it works perfectly on the testing env. So we figure it must be the DB server configuration. 
But what can it be?

I am aware of the peculiarity of the issue but I am desperate and have no choice but to turn to you the StackOverFlow community for help.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**:

Adding `quote()` method code:

```
private String quote(String str) {
    return "\"" + str + "\"";
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

It is important to clarify that once I turn off the HTTP server, restart the server machine and start only the TCP server it works fine against the MySQL DB.

That's what led us to believe there is some blocking/locking mechanism at play here because it seems as though the servers are somehow interrupting each other's access to the DB, even though they use the same DAO code to communicate with it.

Also to clarify, all the components (TCP,HTTP and DB) are on the same machine.

**UPDATE 3**:

Adding `UserDBO`object code:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class UserDBO {

private String uid;
private String token;
private Date registered_date;
private UserStatus userStatus;
private Date unregistered_date;
private int unregistered_count;
private String deviceModel;
private String androidVersion;
}
```

And `UserDboRowMapper` code:

```
public class UserDboRowMapper implements org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper<UserDBO> {
@Override
public UserDBO mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
    return new UserDBO(resultSet.getString(COL_UID),
                        resultSet.getString(COL_TOKEN),
                        resultSet.getDate(COL_REGISTERED_DATE),
                        UserStatus.valueOf(resultSet.getString(COL_USER_STATUS)),
                        resultSet.getDate(COL_UNREGISTERED_DATE),
                        resultSet.getInt(COL_UNREGISTERED_COUNT),
                        resultSet.getString(COL_DEVICE_MODEL),
                        resultSet.getString(COL_ANDROID_VERSION));
}
```

}

Comment: What I meant it not null but an empty ResultSet instead of the row with the correct data...I will edit my question. By the way my code is in the question body and is not undisclosed. Also I would appreciate not resorting to insulting expressions like 'stupid'. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Also worth to mention there is no exception thrown. Simply the query returns an empty ResultSet, for some unexplained reason I am trying to understand here

Comment: Is there any more information I can provide to help understand this issue?

Comment: So when you say `MySQL select returns null` what you mean is that it doesn't return null? Please clarify. Completely. Everything. Your title. Your question. At present it is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the title as well. So what I see happening is `EmptyResultDataAccessException` is thrown by Spring `JdbcTemplate`, which means an empty result set has returned. So the same query against the same DB returns an empty ResultSet from one connection, (while the DB contains a row fitting that query and should return it) and returns properly from a different connection. If there is any more information I can provide please let me know and I will add it promptly.

Comment: does your quote() function work properly? Maybe u could post that part as well

Comment: The quote method code works properly. As I said the exact same setup (TCP and HTTP server communicating with the same MySQL DB) with the same code was tested for several days on the testing env and worked perfectly. So it must be something with DB configuration... I added the quote method code as you requested anyway. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So (1) what is `quote()` (2) why aren't you using `PreparedStatement` which would almost certainly a make `quote()' unnecessary (3) what is the content of the table that you expect to be returned and (4) what are the values of the variables you are supplying to the statement so we can tell what should be returned from it?

Comment: I added quote code to the question body. I can change the code to use PreparedStatement if you think that can help. But locally the query works fine that's why I didn't think that is the issue. The table columns are: uid:String, token:String, registered_date:Date, user_status:String, unregistered:Date, unregistered_count:Int, device_model:String, android_version:String. About what I expect to return, I am adding the UserDBO object to the question body. The parameter values are TABLE_USERS  = 'users', COL_UID = 'uid' and the '?' in the WHERE clause is something like "0542258808"

Comment: Any other information I can give to assist?